# Extract data from an XML string with xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I have an XML string and I need to extract the first three "col" tag in each group of "row". In other words, the output should be the following:

```
['1043100330', 'Smith', 'John', '1043100331', 'Swartz', 'Francis', '1043100332', 'Laff', 'Michael']
```

This is the XML:

```
data = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <processOXIMessageResponse xmlns="urn:com:singun:webservice" xmlns:ns="urn:com:singun:webservice">
         <ns1:processOXIMessageReturn xmlns:ns1="urn:com:singun:webservice">
            <SingunDocument xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" protocol="OXI">
               <sessionId xmlns="">1613762599483</sessionId>
               <command xmlns="" echo="" xsi:type="ServiceProviderGetListResponse">
                  <serviceProviderTable>
                     <colHeading>User Id</colHeading>
                     <colHeading>Last Name</colHeading>
                     <colHeading>First Name</colHeading>
                     <colHeading>Email Address</colHeading>
                     <colHeading>Phone Number</colHeading>
                     <colHeading>Extension</colHeading>
                     <colHeading>Country Code</colHeading>
                     <colHeading>National Prefix</colHeading>
                     <row>
                        <col>1043100330</col>
                        <col>Smith</col>
                        <col>John</col>
                        <col>jsmith@example.com</col>
                        <col>1043101330</col>
                        <col>1330</col>
                        <col>52</col>
                        <col>52</col>
                     </row>
                     <row>
                        <col>1043100331</col>
                        <col>Swartz</col>
                        <col>Francis</col>
                        <col>fswartz@example.com</col>
                        <col>1043101331</col>
                        <col>1331</col>
                        <col>52</col>
                        <col>52</col>
                     </row>
                     <row>
                     <row>
                        <col>1043100332</col>
                        <col>Laff</col>
                        <col>Michael</col>
                        <col>mlaff@example.com</col>
                        <col>1043101332</col>
                        <col>1332</col>
                        <col>52</col>
                        <col>52</col>
                     </row>
                  </serviceProviderTable>
               </command>
            </SingunDocument>
         </ns1:processOXIMessageReturn>
      </processOXIMessageResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The following is my code, but it extracts only the first "col" tag instead of the first three of each group as I would like:

```
        import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

        users = []
        root = ET.fromstring(resp)
        for col in root.iterfind('.//row/col[1]'):
            users.append(col.text)
        print(users)
```

This is the output of my code:

```
['1043100330', '1043100331', '1043100332']
```

Please if you can give me a hand. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take into account the namespaces, as well as the structure of your xml. Try something like:

```
data = root.findall('.//{C}serviceProviderTable//{C}row')
for datum in data:
    entries = datum.findall('.//{C}col')
    users.append([entry.text.strip() for entry in entries[:3]])
for user in users:
    print(user)
```

Output:

```
['1043100330', 'Smith', 'John']
['1043100331', 'Swartz', 'Francis']
['1043100332', 'Laff', 'Michael']
```

Comment: Hi Jack Fleeting, have tested your code and this is the output: 
```` 
1043100330
1043100331
1043100332 
````

Comment: @MarianoMunarriz Don't know what to tell you; it works for me.

Comment: Thank you! It has worked. I had done something wrong.

Comment: @MarianoMunarriz Glad to hear it!